# How to run a python script with cronjob in Ubuntu / Apache

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to set up a cronjob in my Apache2/Ubuntu 20.04 server.

The python file that I want to execute is as follows:

```
def main():
print('TEST')
function()


def function():
    file1 = open("home/username/project/cron_test.txt","a")
    str1 = 'Test2 \n'
    file1.write(str1)
    file1.close() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have defined my cronjob as follows:

```
* * * * * /home/username/project/venv/bin/python3 /home/username/project/cron_test.py
```

When I run the command in putty, it works perfectly fine, and I get my desired output.
However, when I place it in the crontab, the python script doesn't run.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have tried various different ways, such as cd into the project folder and then run it, as well as putting a -f in between the python venv and the code, but I don't get any closer.

Help is appreciated.

Best regards,

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
file1 = open("home/username/project/cron_test.txt","a")
```

to

```
file1 = open("/home/username/project/cron_test.txt","a")
```

Comment: Hi Canasta, thanks for your edit, it did the job and it worked now. Now I wanted to change my code, and only run def function(). I changed the cron task to 

* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 -c 'from home.camielk.BolSellerTool.cron_test import function; function()'

but now it isn't working anymore. Any more solutions?

Comment: It seems there is nothing wrong. Difference is `/home/username/project/venv/bin/python3` changed to `/usr/bin/python3`. Check this, and Typo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Try converting your script to an executable python script,

1. Change your cronjob to `* * * * * /home/username/project/cron_test.py`
2. Make your script executable, i.e. in terminal run `chmod +x cron_test.py`
3. Add the following to the top of your script file: `#!/usr/bin/python3` (Or wherever your python binary is located)